# Shared data object model issues whel using JSON as transport in Microservices

Tags: json, serialization, microservices

We are trying to come out with an Architecture for our new product where in we are looking for Microservices.
Suppose I have following Microservices

1.Position Data Service - works with Client+Securities(Bonds) data

2.Valuation Service - works with Client+Security+Security's Valuation data

We are thinking on having Json Data structure / hirarachy something like this:

```
Client - Client's attributes

       - List - Security - Security's attributes

                         - List - Valuation - Valuation attributes
```

Since every micro-service will receive it's respective input data in JSON and it has to parse it java object (Client.java, Security.java etc, Valuation.java)
We are thinking of having all java classes (object models-Client.java, Security.java, Valuation.java etc) in a separate java project and use it as jar dependency in all micro-services so that they can serialize / deserialize JSON into these objects and work accordingly.

Now since

1.we are sharing the object model in all microservices

2.Any change in Object model will impact all services

3.They are somewhere becoming dependent on each other as in suppose Position Data service just take care of Client and security's attributes but still when deserialize r serialize using the shared object model, will have complete herarchy Client-[List Of Security[List Of Valuation]]
Are we violating design approach behind micro-services where we say that every microservice is completely isolated with other one?

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue. Can you tell me how you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue and I feel the answer is embrace redundancy. Each Microservice will define its own model and be able to deserialise into that model (ignoring unknown properties). That way you adhere to the open/closed principle by only adding new properties to your models when necessary and isolate your services from one another.